# The form of a set of positive integers that contains $k+1$ whenever it contains $k$

Tags: proof-verification, induction

I've seen there are lots of proofs by mathematical induction on the site, yet I haven't seen a problem like mine (or at least couldn't pattern my problem after the other).

"Let $m$ be the smallest element of set $A\subseteq\mathbb{N}$. If $k+1$ is the element of $A$ whenever a natural number $k$ is, then $A=\{n\in\mathbb{N}:n\geq m\}$."

---

I think I should create another set for which only the first part of the problem is true, but not $$A=\{n\in\mathbb{N}:n\geq m\}.$$ Then conclude from the former information that this is really true.

---

(1) Let's assume $a=m$; since $m\in A\subseteq\mathbb{N}$, $a$ is a natural number in $A$.

(2) Let $K\subseteq\mathbb{N}$, let $m$ be its smallest element, and for all $k\in K$ there's $k+1$ in $K$. For this set (1) also holds, since some $k=m$ must be the element of $K$.

(3) If $m$ is the smallest element of $K$, then $m+1$ is the next element in the set ($m+1\in K$), and so on. This is true because of the assumption (2) "for any natural $k\in K$ there's $k+1\in K$". Therefore now we know that $K$ contains all natural numbers $k$, starting from $m$: $$K=\{k\in\mathbb{N}:k\geq m\}.$$

Is this a good proof? If someone could drop a hint I'd be glad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making it more complicated than it needs to be. I'm not at all sure what part (1) is about, for example.

Note that since $m$ is the smallest element of $A$ and $A\subseteq\Bbb N,$ then we can immediately conclude that $$A\subseteq\{n\in\Bbb N:n\ge m\}.\tag{$\star$}$$ This is because if $a\in A,$ then $a\in\Bbb N$ since $A\subseteq\Bbb N,$ and $a\ge m$ since $m$ is the least element of $A;$ thus, $a\in\{n\in\Bbb N:n\ge m\},$ and since this holds for all $a\in A,$ then $(\star)$ holds.

All that remains is to show that if $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $n\ge m,$ then $n\in A,$ from which the reverse inclusion of $(\star)$ follows, and so we have equality. That's where induction comes in handy. The idea is to note that if $n\in\Bbb N$ and $n\ge m,$ then either $n=m$ or $n=m+k$ for some positive integer $k.$ Proceed by induction on $k$ to show that all such $n$ are elements of $A.$

Let me know if you have any trouble, or just want to check your reasoning.

Comment: Part (1) is base of induction, so I picked some a=m, and checked that it's in A. I don't know how you can immediately conclude ("star") from just that, since A can be {1}, (m =1, the smallest element). I agree, though, that if you add that "for any natural k in A there's k+1 in A", you can conclude ("star"). Maybe you meant: just from given information (m is the smallest element of A which is a subset of N) we need to prove the part about "for all natural k in A there's also k+1". Just to add, I think I understand what you meant, and I was going from the opposite direction. I'll try again.

Comment: $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $n\geq m$. Since $n\geq m$ means $n=m$ or $n>m$, and since $m$ is by definition a natural number, we need to prove that if $n\in\mathbb{N}$ $n\geq m$. This implies that $n=m+k, \forall k\in\mathbb{N}$. Induction: 1) base $k=1$, since $m$ is a natural number, $m+1$ is also a natural number. 2) define a set $B\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ for which $n=m+b$ is true.  3) Since $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $b\in\mathbb{N}$; replacing $b$ with $b+1$, $n=m+b+1$, since $n=m+b$, the former equation equals $n+1$, which must be an element of natural numbers. Therefore it works for all $b\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: I've expanded my answer to make it clearer what I was talking about with $(\star)$. Your induction attempt has a great many issues, both in what it says that you're trying to prove, and how you go about it. If possible, I'd like to try to help you get past these issues, but I need some information from you. In particular, what is your definition of a natural number?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to merge accounts, and that one was made without login. (roro) I tried, but it says my profile link is invalid... whatever. Now I cannot comment on that answer. I'm sorry I'm doing exactly what is against the rules (replying to the answer in "an answer", but I figured, because I've already chosen the best one, this won't hurt).

---

I didn't see that you used "$\subseteq$" instead of "$=$". ...

Natural number is a positive integer. Set of natural numbers is a set with $1$ as a starting number, and the next number is bigger by $1$ from the previous.